# How to unit test AWS SDK DynamoDB .NET core 6?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, asp.net-core-6.0

I have followed a tutorial on creating a Web API with DynamoDB as database. Now I want to write unit tests, but I have no clue how, since I do not have a repository or repository interface.
In another post, I read that you could mock the DynamoDBContext interface, but I still would not know where to go from there.

**My controller**

```
namespace FollowerService.Controllers;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FollowerController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IDynamoDBContext _context; //lets us use the DynamoDB
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public FollowerController(IDynamoDBContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _context = context;
        _configuration = configuration; 
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Follower>> GetAllFollowers(string userId)
    {
        var i = await _context.QueryAsync<Follower>(userId).GetRemainingAsync();
        return i;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddFollower(Follower follower)
    {
        await _context.SaveAsync(follower);
        SQSProcessor sqsProcessor = new SQSProcessor(_configuration);
        await sqsProcessor.SQSPost(follower);
        //await SQSPost(follower);
        return Ok(follower);
        
    }
```

**My question:**
Can I get one example from a good unit test that would test the get or post?
If I do not need to write unit tests for this controller for any reason, please also let me know why

Comment: there is no acutal unit test included in your question...  Seems you put no effort into bringing up a valid unit test. So the questiion is: What do you want to test in your example? Is it the controller or the dynamo context? 

PS: Maybe also you want to use Repository pattern... this allows you to test the DAL independent form your controller.

PPS: maybe you should use DTOs instead of entities in your controller

Answer (score 0):

you simply have to mock the dynamo db context within your Test:

```
var userId = "xy";
var _context = Mock.Of<IDynamoDBContext>();
Mock.Get(_context)
    .Setup(x => x._context.QueryAsync<Follower>(userId))
    .ReturnsAsync(new Follower {UserId = userId});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work because `QueryAsync` returns `AsyncSearch<T>`.

Comment: A solution has finally been developed by the AWS team, whereby you can subclass `AsyncSearch<T>` as shown in this issue comment https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/772#issuecomment-1242558047